# How to check all database for availability in CI 2

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have config file database.php with 5 databases.

How can I get 500 error with message "Site is not available" in all pages, if one of a database is not available?

Comment: So, are you saying you want to shut down access to the site if even one database can't connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it very interesting your question and have been doing some research to solve your problem.
I tell you my solution: the first is to activate the hooks, so in your config.php file make this change:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Once activated the hooks, you need to create a new hook, for it in the file config/hooks.php put something like the following:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
  'class'    => 'DBTest',
  'function' => 'index',
  'filename' => 'dbtest.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks',
  'params'   => array(),
);
```

Thus, your hook kicks in once the controller has been instantiated, but has run no method yet. This is neccesary to use $CI = &get_instance()

To finish create the file /application/hooks/dbtest.php with content similar to the following:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class DBTest {

  function index() {

    $CI = &get_instance();

    $databases = array(
      'mysqli://user1:pass1@host1/db1',
      'mysqli://user2:pass2@host2/db2',
      'mysqli://user3:pass3@host3/db3',
      'mysqli://user4:pass4@host4/db4',
      'mysqli://user5:pass5@host5/db5',
    );

    foreach ($databases as $dsn) {

      $db_name = substr(strrchr($dsn, '/'), 1);
      $CI->load->database($dsn);
      $CI->load->dbutil();

      if(!$CI->dbutil->database_exists($db_name)) {
        // if connection details incorrect show error
        show_error("Site is not available: can't connect to database $db_name");                
      }
    }

  }
}
```

You must use dsn for $CI->load->database() in this way we can handle the error instead of Code Igniter when it tries to load the database.

Hope this helps.